Jackson-core related issue
I was trying to upgrade jackson-core dependency in buil.gradle
from 2.15.2 to 2.17.2, but below code snippet causing issue while serializing
APIGAtewayProxyResponseEvent event = new APIGAtewayProxyResponseEvent();
Bean bean = new ObjectMapper.readValue(event.getBody, Bean.class)
error in readValue()

What exactly is the issue? How is it related to Gradle?

I am trying to upgrade jackson-core dependency in build.gradle from 2.15.2 to 2.17.2. Above snippet worked fine in 2.15.2 but causing issue in 2.17.2 version upgrade

Is event.getBody a method? If so, shouldn't it be event.getBody()?
